# Admin.listTables() Failed to getTableDescriptor()

Tags: bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

Trying to get list of tables from bigtable and I get the following error;

```
15/08/19 12:21:51 INFO grpc.BigtableSession: Opening connection for projectId test-xxx-xxx-xxx, zoneId us-central1-b, clusterId hbase-test1, on data host bigtable.googleapis.com, table admin host bigtabletableadmin.googleapis.com.
java.io.IOException: Failed to getTableDescriptor() on customer
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractBigtableAdmin.getTableDescriptor(AbstractBigtableAdmin.java:264)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractBigtableAdmin.getTableDescriptors(AbstractBigtableAdmin.java:146)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractBigtableAdmin.listTables(AbstractBigtableAdmin.java:140)
at com.zulily.dataservice.connectivity.BigTableListCommand.run(BigTableListCommand.java:38)
```

As given on the example(https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/blob/master/java/simple-cli/pom.xml); I have the following entry in the pom

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigtable</groupId>
  <artifactId>bigtable-hbase-1.1</artifactId>
  <version>0.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
  <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty.alpn</groupId>
    <artifactId>alpn-boot</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.0.v20141016</version>
</dependency>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  We really recommend a later version, such as 1.7.0_79.  Which would mean that you alpn-boot version should be 7.1.3.v20150130.

Comment: Also, if you are trying to do this in an IDE, such as JIRA, you need to make sure that it is adding the -Xbootpath value at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have anymore information about the cause of the IOException?